# How to print the size of raw pointer?

Tags: rust, raw-pointer

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:p}", std::mem::size_of::<*const u32>());
}
```

When I tried this in the playground it failed:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `usize: Pointer` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:22
  |
2 |     println!("{:p}", std::mem::size_of::<*const u32>());
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Pointer` is not implemented for `usize`
  |
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Pointer::fmt`
  = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Is there a way to print the size of raw pointer like `*const u32`?

Comment: `mem::size_of` returns usize, so you should just use `{}` as format, not `{:p}`.

Answer (score 6):

```rust
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<*const u32>());
```

`{:p}` requires the result of the to-be-printed-thing to satisfy `Pointer`, but `size_of` returns `usize` which does not satisfy `Pointer`. You can print a `usize` simply with `{}`.

`{:p}` is essentially used to print a *memory location*, which is not something that `size_of` returns.